# Android Management API: List of Enterprises/Policies?

Tags: google-apis-explorer, android-management-api

This is driving me nuts. I've successfully followed the [Android Management API Quickstart](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb) to create a project/enterprise/policy and install it on a device.

I stupidly didn't write down the enterprise or policy IDs. I tried to create a new set, but the non-enterprise email now gives an error that it's already part of another EMM.

Is there a place in the console where I can see a list of the enterprises and/or policies that I've created? Where are these stored?

Edit: I found the `enterprises.get` [method in the API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises/get) but if I put `enterprises/*` in the name field (per the validation) I get a 400 error indicating `Invalid enterprise id. Provide a valid id.` so I'm unsure how to move forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the `enterprise` you created by logging into [play.google.com/work](https://play.google.com/work) with the account that was used to create it.

Click on Admin Settings to see the `Organization name` and `Organization ID`

[image: Admin Settings]

And to find the `policies` of all the devices you have enrolled to this `enterprise`, you can simply call the `API` - `enterprises.devices.list` entering the parent in the form `enterprises/{enterpriseId}` [ enterpriseId here is the `OrganizationID` that you get from the above steps ]

This would list all the devices attached to the `enterprise` and in the response you can find `policyName` of each device.

Comment: Hello - it appears that organizations are not the same thing as enterprises... when I try any of these API calls with the organization ID I'm getting a permission error (403). Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the method `enterprises.policies.list` to list all the policies ever created for this enterprise.

Comment: Thanks @Fred - what I mean is that the Organization ID that displays on the page does not appear to be a valid Enterprise ID. When I try to use the any of the API links (listed in my original question) it tries to authenticate via oAuth popup and then says my user doesn't have the right permissions, even though I'm using the account that created it.

Comment: @Lauren are you sure the account that you are using is the account with which you created it ? Because the ```OrganizationId``` is for sure the ```enterprise```, also make sure in the OAuth popup you select the same account to authenticate.

And like @Fred suggested you can use ```enterprises.policies.list``` to list all the policies ever created but the reason I've suggested ```enterprises.devices.list``` is because you will get the devices which are alive and attached to the ```enterprise``` and it's easy to identify which device has which policy.

Comment: Thanks @Sudhu. It's worth mentioning that even when selecting the correct enterprise ID (Organization ID), a 403 error occurs for G Suite users. There seems to be no way to link an existing G Suite organization/enterprise with the Android Management API. You need to create an arbitrary Gmail account. Has anyone found a way around this?