# Domain and domain user from the enterprise in Android management api EMM

Tags: android, android-management-api

I am creating a new EMM console for many organizations.
By using android management API I created an enterprise, where I could receive only the enterprise id I could not get organization name and sign in user email from the [enterprise value](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises#Enterprise).

Can someone help me to fetch the data?

Comment: Please have a look at the link. I have answered for the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535838/8251967

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is only possible with the [EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/enterprises) and unfortunately Google are deprecating the access to it.

You'll need to place a feature request for the Android Management API, I guess.